# Pass custom object to Arrays.asList

Tags: java, arrays

Say I have a Person class and I am trying to create a list as;

```
Person p1 = new Person("first", "id1");         
Person p2 = new Person("dummy", "id1"); 
Person p3 = new Person("second", "id2");         
Person p4 = new Person("third", "id1");         
List<Person> asList = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3, p4);
```

Now my question is instead of passing the indivdual Person objects to Arrays.asList()

can I pass a combined list, something like

```
List<Person> asList = Arrays.asList(combinedPersonObjs);
```

I have tried many things, but am getting casting errors.

Please help

**Note:** The number of Person objects is dynamic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you can do

```
Person[] combinedPersonObjs = { p1, p2, p3, p4 };
List<Person> asList = Arrays.asList(combinePersonObjs);
```

If you don't know the number of `Person` objects in advance, then presumably you don't have one variable identifier for each object. I suggest you simply do something like

```
List<Person> asList = new ArrayList<Person>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPersons; i++)
    asList.add(new Person(ithName(i), "id" + i));
```

Comment: Actually I am not sure how many Person objs there might be...it is dynamic....can be p1,p2, p3, p4,....p10

Comment: +1 In fact, this is the real usage of that method, and `Arrays.asList(p1,p2,p3,p4)` is just syntactic sugar, internally it too creates an array.

Comment: @testndtv, But if it's dynamic you don't have separate variables, `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, ...? If you don't know the number of persons in advance, I suggest you create an `ArrayList<Person>` and add them in a loop.

Comment: @testndtv Then why don't you put them in a list straight away?

Answer (score 2):

put all objects in an array and pass this array to Arrays.asList()

You can find the documentation here..
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

You could bypass the array completely (I don't quite understand why you're using it) and create an anonymous class derived from list thus:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>(){{
   add(new Person("first", "id1"));
   add(new Person("second", "id2"));
   // etc..
}};
```

Note that this uses initialisation within a static block and creates an inner class (which may cause some confusion if you're not expecting it). Note that inner block can loop and add a dynamic number of objects (as you've noted in your question edit).

But why not just do:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
persons.add(new Person(...));
```

etc.?

Answer (score 0):

A **List** Object can hold multiple types of **Objects**. So in a **List** you can hold a **Person Object** and also a **List** of persons like this

```
List<Person> myList = new List<Person>();
Person p1 = new Person();
Person p2 = new Person();
myList.add(p1);
myList.add(p2);
Person p3 = new Person();
List<Object> globalList= new List<Object>();
globalList.add(myList );
globalList.add(p3);
```

Comment: I think this is really nasty. You can put stuff in trivially, but how do you *easily* pull the objects out? Who knows what's in a List<Object> ?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't create a local reference, you can do this :

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
for( /* add here gardian */ ) {
    list.add(new Person("first", "id1"));
}
```